# TypeScript TS2339 error in React component: Property 'xyz' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes...'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to create a simple React component that takes any properties. The following syntax with `any` refuses to work (unexpected token just before `<`):

```
export class ValidatedInput extends React.Component<any, any> {...}
```

The error goes away by replacing `any` with `{}` (can someone please explain the difference):

```
export class ValidatedInput extends React.Component<{}, {}> {...}
```

However, now when I use the component in another file, it complains about the properties that I send into the component. For example:

```
<ValidatedInput
    entity={book}
/>
```

This gives me an error:

> TS2339: Property 'entity' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes' & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode;...'

What's TypeScript upset about? Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a guess - make sure you are declaring your compoent in tsx file.

Comment: That was a great guess @Amid! I was porting code over from ES6 and forgot to change the filename. If you could put your guess in an answer, I will mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like compiler does not understand that you are using tsx syntax. Verify that your file has 'tsx' extension.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issues before, first verify the file type is .tsx as suggested by @Amid. If that doesn't work. Check that you have saved your changes. In my case, I made lots of changes to several files and I did not save all the files I modified, the error went away when I saved all the files.