# TS2339 when trying to conditionally disable a link

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

Within a table, I have a link which I want to conditionally gray-out. The following code worked just fine before updating:

```js
<Link to="#"
  onClick={e => { e.preventDefault(); }}
  disabled={this.props.finalisingStatus} >
      Finalize up to here
</Link>
```

In the header, I did a `import { Link } from "react-router-dom"` as usual. Within the interface of the component, I define a property `finalisingStatus: Boolean;`.

After updating to Typescript (version 4.41.2) I obtain a TS2339 error:

> Property 'disabled' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes> & Readonly> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'

How can I fix that?

PS: [TypeScript TS2339 error in React component: Property 'xyz' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes...'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45724978/typescript-ts2339-error-in-react-component-property-xyz-does-not-exist-on-typ) is somewhat related, but not the issue in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to render `Link` conditionally, as `disabled` might not be a valid prop of `Link`. This way, you will not need to worry about overwriting the click event that is triggered by `Link`.

If it is disabled, you render your `span` element with the disabled styles.

Here is a simple example:

```
render () {
  const { isDisabled } = this.props;
  if(isDisabled){
    return <span className='disabled'>{this.props.linktext}</span>;
  } else {
    return <Link to={this.props.to}>{this.props.linktext}</Link>;
  }
}
```